# Meteor GroundDB seems to lack persistence

Tags: mongodb, meteor, persistence

I have the following code.

```
Meteor.startup(function () {  
    Cells = new Ground.Collection('cells', { connection: null });

    console.log("Number of cells: " + Cells.find().count());

    if (Cells.find().count() == 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < Session.get('cellsLat'); i++) { 
            for (j = 0; j < Session.get('cellsLng'); j++) { 
                Cells.insert({ i: i, j: j, visible: true });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

After every restart and reload (pressing the reload button in the browser), Cells.find().count() equals 0.

Am I missing something obvious, here?

Comment: It is true that the GroundDB documentation is scarce. I would like to use it, but from the documentation I am not able to figure out if it will suit my needs. I was wondering if adding the `cleanupLocalData: false` parameter would help. So you would have `Cells = new Ground.Collection('cells', { connection: null, cleanupLocalData: false });`

Comment: Also, I am wondering if this other example from the documentation would work better:
  `// Ground an existing Meteor.Collection  
  var list = new Meteor.Collection(null);
  // just ground the database and map on suffix `list`
  Ground.Collection(list, 'list');`